# How to add a proper Outlined Edit Text in my application?

Tags: android, android-edittext, material-design

I am trying to make my edit text into something like this

[image]

but my application crashes when I applied the `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"`

but when I removed the style it runs perfectly again.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_last_name"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:errorEnabled="true">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/lastnamename_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Lastname" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

>

```
 05-23 14:53:23.908 5461-5461/com.cremlic_it.eloanapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.cremlic_it.eloanapplication, PID: 5461
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at com.cremlic_it.eloanapplication.fragment.ApplicationFragment.onCreateView(ApplicationFragment.java:46)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2539)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:875)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1227)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1293)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:710)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2063)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1853)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1808)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1715)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:143)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
        at com.cremlic_it.eloanapplication.fragment.ApplicationFragment.onCreateView(ApplicationFragment.java:46) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2539) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:875) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1227) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1293) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:710) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2063) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1853) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1808) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1715) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:143) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:240)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkMaterialTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:215)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:143)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainTintedStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:116)
        at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:403)
        at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:382)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
        at com.cremlic_it.eloanapplication.fragment.ApplicationFragment.onCreateView(ApplicationFragment.java:46) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2539) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:875) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1227) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1293) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:710) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2063) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1853) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1808) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1715) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:143) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post your stack trace when it crashes with that style

Comment: Which `AppTheme` are you using?

Comment: @SaurabhThorat added

Comment: @JeelVankhede I am using the default AppTheme

Comment: make sure your apptheme is extending from `Theme.MaterialComponents`

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).

Comment: You'll need to use **Bridge theme** to get rid of crash I guess. (I.e. `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar.Bridge`) as parent of your AppTheme or switch your project to AndroidX artifact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the parent of AppTheme as below.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The outline box only works when you use 
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
Any of the other versions does not display outlined box.